# Select column from table2 based on date of table1

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my invoice detail table I have:
invoiceno, invoicedate, itemno, price and I need to get the "cost" from another table that contains multiple records for the same item but different cost for different dates.

How can I get the cost based on invoicedate in sql server 2012.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

but this should work for now:

```
select a.invoiceno,a.invoicedate,a.itemno,a.price,b.cost
from invoice a
inner join othertable b
on a.invoiceno = b.invoiceno
and a.invoicedate = b.invoicedate
```

Comment: I failed to mention that the dates in "cost" table do not exactly match invoice date, they are date ranges ex: on 01/01/2015 the cost was say 10.00 but on 06/01/2015 the cost went up to 12.00 so I want to pickup the correct cost based on the invoice date.

Comment: @Carlos this will give you the cost for the date associated with the invoice #